# Passing string as parameter onClick of dynamic button created in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am creating a dynamic button in javascript and calling a function on its click,but I am not able to pass string parameter to it,what shoud be the proper code.
I am doing this.

```
  document.getElementById(divfield).innerHTML +="<input type='button' value='-'class='remove_this"+i+"' onclick='  removed("+i+",'"+s+"')  '>";
```

here i is a integer,and s is a variable holding string.how should i pass string variable.

Comment: Could you create jsfiddle page for us?

Comment: What did you actually get from this code?

Comment: whatever m passing as string,it is giving as variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have missed some `quotation` mark on your code, if you try this:

```
innerHTML +="<input ..... onclick=' removed(" + i + ",\" " + s + "\ ") '>";
```

there will not any problem...

by your code, `input` element will be created like this: (notice to `onclick` attribute):

```
<input type="button" value="-" class="remove_this1" onclick="  removed(1," ss') '>
```

if: (i = 1) and (s = "ss") for example

Comment: thanks,this was the code,it worked for me,but I tried it by self before you posted.But thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want something like this:

```
var div = document.getElementById('divfield');

var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'button';
input.value = '-';
input.setAttribute('class', 'remove_this' + i);
input.onclick = function () {
    removed(i,s)
}

div.appendChild(input);
```

jsfiddle: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PX6C3/)

Comment: yes somewhat but,i want to pass a string onclick of the dynamic button

Comment: Well thanks everyone,
I m able to achieve this,so sharing the piece of code,may be anyone else can get help.

      document.getElementById(divfield).innerHTML +="<input type='button' value='-'class='remove_this"+i+"' onclick='  removed("+i+",\""+s+"\")  '>";